# Factor polynomial with specific common variables (terms)

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I want to factor the following polynomial:

```
b*p - b*q + c*q - c*r - a*(p - r)
```

When I use the function `FactorTerms`. I get the following result:

```
FactorTerms[b*p - b*q + c*q - c*r - a*(p - r), {p, q, r}]
// Output: (-a)*p + b*p - b*q + c*q + a*r - c*r

FactorTerms[b*p - b*q + c*q - c*r - a*(p - r), {a, b, c}]
// Output: (-a)*p + b*p - b*q + c*q + a*r - c*r
```

Using simplify actually gives me factors:

```
Simplify[b*p - b*q + c*q - c*r - a*(p - r)]
// Output: b*(p - q) + c*(q - r) + a*(-p + r)
```

The only problem is that I wanted the common terms to be `p`, `q` and `r`.

How can I tell Mathematica to factor a polynomial with specific common variables?

Thanks.

Comment: The `Simplify` result shows a sum, not a product. This is not going to be amenable to factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collect` here.

```
Collect[b*p - b*q + c*q - c*r - a*(p - r), {p, q, r}]
```

> (-a + b) p + (-b + c) q + (a - c) r

It will also work for `{a, b, c}` as above.
Also another fun thing with `Collect`. We can apply `Factor` to each coefficient obtained for `{p,q,r}` and I tweaked your polynomial a bit so p has a coefficient that can be factored.

```
Collect[b^2*p - b*q + c*q - c*r - a^2*(p - r), {p, q, r}, Factor]
```

> -(a - b) (a + b) p + (-b + c) q + (a^2 - c) r

Comment: Thanks PlatoManiac. I knew Mathematica has such a function. Couldn't just figure out its name.

Comment: I have a question. Why does `FactorTerms` expands all the terms instead of combining some of them in the above case?

Comment: I guess this is a planned design choice. `Collect` gives us lots of more power how we would like to combine our preferred terms in a polynomial. I gave an example above. By the way you should wait before accepting answers. This will inspire others to also contribute new answers sometimes :)

Comment: Thanks @PlatoManiac. :)